# how to print text and variable's values in the same line with Serial.println in Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide

I've this code:

```
 Serial.print("x:");
 Serial.print(x);
 Serial.print(" y: ");
 Serial.println(y);
```

and works fine. There's an example of the output:

```
x:41 y: 31
```

but I wonder if there's a way to write the four sentences in one with something like:

```
Serial.println("x:"+x+" y:"+y);
```

that returns an error:

```
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [4]' to binary 'operator+'
```

Any idea?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution:  Serial.println(String("x:") + x + String("y:") + y);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String concatenation can be very useful when you need to display a combination of values and the descriptions of those values into one String to display via serial communication.

```
 int sValor = analogRead(A5); 
 String StrUno = "Valor Sensor N°5: ";
 String StrDos = StrUno + sValor ;
 Serial.println(StrDos);
```

We can concatenate multiple values, forming a string with all the data and then send it.
This can also be used with LCD dislpay.

Answer (score 35):

There is a quicker way:
Just convert your output directly to a String:

```
Serial.println((String)"x:"+x+" y:"+y);
```

Answer (score 3):

In PlatformIO for arduino works good (example):

```
Serial.println("R: " + String(variableR) + ", G: " + String(variableG) + ", B: " + String(variableB));
```

Answer (score 2):

Either way, there needs to be an explicit conversion from int to String like seen in Guest's post - worked for me in the following way:

```
String(intVariable)
```

In the post of user3923880 this is missing and the code does not work in my Arduino IDE (Version 1.8.13). What worked for me, for example:

```
String outString = stringVar1 + '\t' + String(time) + '\n'; 
Serial.print(outString);
```

With *\t* being a tab delimiter and *\n* a line break.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is this:

```
char buffer[40];
sprintf(buffer, "The %d burritos are %s degrees F", numBurritos, tempStr);
Serial.println(buffer);
```